# Parallel solar systems to single load?

Tags: solar-cell

I'm trying to help non-technical brother by SMS.  Not easy.  He has two MPPT controllers of [this type](https://www.teknistore.com/en/electrical-equipment-and-supplies/41669-30-40-50-60-100a-mppt-solar-controller-lcd-solar-charge-controller-accuracy-dual-usb-solar-panel-battery-regulator.html).  They show the load connected directly to the controller.

What I am wondering is whether the load can be connected in parallel to two of these?

The only system I ever worked on had an A/B/both/off switch to allow disconnecting half the system for maintenance or service.  So the controllers had no separate load connection.

[image]

Can these be used this way (load connectors unused)?  Or instead of connecting batteries load and controllers in parallel, have the load connectors go in parallel to such a switch?

Or would it work to isolate with a heavy-duty diode like this?

[image]

Comment: Connecting outputs together is generally a bad idea unless they're specifically designed to allow it. What are you trying to achieve by connecting them together?

Comment: The diodes are a must, you can't just connect two batteries with different charge states in parallel, unless you want to risk **very** high currents. However, your second scheme makes no sense either, the way you've drawn it. This is an electrical engineering site, please use electrical schematics to make unambigously clear what you plan to do.

Comment: The controllers have load connectors separate from charging connectors.

Comment: that doesn't actually answer any of our questions.

Comment: Get your brother to communicate with stack exchange directly instead of going through a 3rd party (you).

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use method A. You may be able to use method B: can you talk to the supplier?

Method A effectively puts two batteries in parallel, forming one battery. This is unusual because it makes it difficult to evenly charge both legs of the parallel battery, which effectively reduces the size (and the lifetime) of the parallel battery. Still, sometimes this is the only option people have.

But also, in your case, method A effectively puts both controller outputs in parallel. Most battery charge controllers depend on the battery for regulation, and when you connect another controller there they don't regulate properly, giving you wild swings and excessive noise on the battery voltage. Even when the regulators aren't wildly swinging, they will disagree about the state of charge: one may be trying to equalize, while the other is trying to float.

Also, method A can give you a large (potentially fatal) current surge at the moment you connect the batteries, but that's no worse than jump starting a car, and can be handled with care.

Method B puts a diode in line with your load, which looses power and efficiency, and only partially isolates the two batteries and two controllers, but the partial isolation is normally enough to allow the two batteries to each charge effectively, and may be enough to prevent wild voltage swings. You still have the problem with the two controllers not being in the same state, and that is where talking to the manufacturer can help. You want to avoid situations like having one battery stuck in 'equalize' state (which might cause overheating), so you need to have the controllers configured in a way which will avoid that.

Comment: Can't talk to the supplier; not even easy to talk to my brother who wants to install these things.  Method A is what was in a place I visited years ago in the Amazon jungle.  If I had thought of it at the time, I would have told them to put those diodes in, for the reasons you mention.  Even more of an issue with my brother's controllers, since they have additional circuits to monitor the load and could be disagreeing with each other.